# Is there a single example of an outsider considered a "crank" publishing a ground-breaking result that was found to be correct (in the last 30 years)?

Tags: research-process

I'm interested mainly in mathematical and related fields, in which several important and famous open questions exist (e.g., Riemann Hypothesis).
Almost every day a new "amateur" scholar (meaning, someone with *no formal affiliation* to a reputable research institute, or someone who does not have any *track record of peer-reviewed publications*
in reputable journals or conferences in the area) publishes into cyber-space a new manuscript alleged to solve a major open problem in mathematics or related fields. Some established researchers then consider this a work of "cranckery" (i.e., an amateur attempt that is not only false, but is mostly meaningless and hence impossible to verify since the argument is so confused and unstructured that it is hard to identify any meaningful statement to verify).
On the other hand, the amateur would usually claim that his/her proof is correct, and would feel frustrated that the established scholars ignore his/her breakthrough, perhaps because they are "outsiders", or that it is harmful for the "establishment" to acknowledge the breakthrough.

***This leads to a simple question**: is there a single example in the last 30 years in which such an amateur whose work was *considered a crank* when published, was in retrospect vindicated and proved correct?*

**Clarifications**: examples of somewhat less known, but still established academics with a track record and an affiliation, who solved a moderately big open question do exist. I'm asking about a clear person identified as a "crank" whose work was then proved to be correct.

---

**EDIT: I decided to accept Dan Romik's answer** as the closest to a complete answer to my question. There were many good and surprising answers that I didn't know about. But my criteria were somewhat strict, so none of those fall within the desired quest: an (1) *amateur*, i.e., someone with *NO* research affiliation (2) whose work of a *mathematical nature* was (3) *considered a "work of crank"* (even when extending the time limit to ~80 years back, to make sure "affiliation" and "crank" have the same meaning as today).

The closest example is indeed Dan Shechtman's work that was dismissed as pseudoscience. But Shechtman was a researcher with a *clear and respected  affiliation*. And as Dan Romik's comments, theories that are considered "crankery" at first can be vindicated in retrospect *in the natural sciences*, but much less so in mathematics. So Shechtman falls in both *math* and *no affiliation* criteria.

Another great example is that of 1952, Kurt Heegner, which I didn't know about. I would have accepted this I believe, had I not read in comments that Heegner *was* in fact considered a serious mathematician and *not* an amateur or an outsider.

Yitang Zhang's example is also close, but although he wasn't considered an established researcher, his work when published was never considered "crankery" as far as I know, but quite immediately identified as an important contribution.

Comment: Maybe "last 30 years" is a bit too restrictive? Mind you, that means post 1992. Sticking with modern examples seems important though. Maybe 50 years (or even 70, to make Heegner fit) would be better?

Comment: @Arno, yes, maybe 50 years is more relevant. The point is that I'm interested in academia as it is today. While in the past things may have been less formal and less specialized. So the term crank would not be relevant.

Comment: Different questions in HSM SE that may still be of interest to readers of this question: [Did amateurs ever produce important proofs or similar?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7606/3869) and [What are some of the earliest mentions of scientific "cranks"?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8256/3869)

Comment: **Mod's note**: if you have an example or an argument that there are no examples, please use the answer box. If you have an anecdote, or a possible answer you're not sure about, or any other commentary, please put it [in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147700/discussion-on-question-by-dilworth-is-there-a-single-example-of-an-outsider-cons). This question already has 17 (!!) real answers, so anything even slightly resembling an answer in the comments will be removed without warning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct answer is most likely “no”, but as with [Russell’s teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot), it would be next to impossible to prove that an example of the scenario you’re describing does not exist.

By way of an argument to support my answer, that isn’t quite a proof of non-existence, I can suggest the following: for mathematicians it is usually very easy to recognize who is a crank and who isn’t. And a defining chracteristic of cranks is that when someone is a crank, they are a crank all the way; they can’t be a crank up to the time they suddenly start doing genuine (let alone groundbreaking) work. So the hypothetical situation described in the question is (essentially) impossible, almost by definition.

**Edit:** as @MaximalIdeal points out, there do seem to be genuine counterexamples to what I wrote above (at least one, dating from 1952). I stand by my reasoning above as being the justification for my belief, but acknowledge that what I wrote isn’t universally true and in rare situations someone can be regarded as a crank but still end up surprising everyone with legitimately good mathematical work.

Comment: I think I gave a counterexample to your post. Nonetheless I agree with your sentiment.

Comment: It just isn't true that cranks are cranks all the way.  Look at de Branges, Mochizuki, Lang (though his crankery was always non-mathematical).

Comment: @NoahSnyder these are serious mathematicians who started believing they had proved something they didn’t. I wouldn’t consider them cranks, although I agree de Branges’ case is a borderline case. To me, they represent a phenomenon that, while interesting, isn’t quite the same as the phenomenon of cranks.

Comment: There are quite a few cranks that study torsion fields or decipher bible codes alongside doing actual research in mathematics.

Comment: @Džuris all of us are probably regarded as delusional by someone, somewhere for some belief that we hold that is unrelated to mathematics. If you stretch the definition of a crank to encompass this type of thing, the whole concept of a crank becomes pretty useless IMO. My answer is limited to _mathematical_ cranks, which I think is closer to OP’s intent than what you’re suggesting.

Comment: @NoahSnyder The existence of serious mathematicians who subsequently became cranks is quite a different proposition from the existence of cranks who subsequently became serious mathematicians.

Answer (score 65):

This answer takes the following liberties:

(1) The field is experimental, not theoretical.

(2) The person had legitimate affiliation and wasn't amateur, but was publicly decried as being a crank by noted scholars.

Nevertheless, I'm adding it because it seems to be aligned with the spirit of the question.

[Dan Shechtman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Shechtman) is a metallurgist who reported for the first time the existence of 'quasi-crystals', an atomic arrangement which appeared to violate fundamental laws of crystallography. He was famously called a 'quasi-scientist' by the celebrated chemist & Nobel laureate Linus Pauling. His own team told him to read the textbook and not make ridiculous claims. These jibes are tantamount to accusations of crankery. Anyhow, the results were published and independently verified over decades, ultimately leading to Shechtman being awarded the Nobel Prize in 2011.

Comment: Interesting, but also not within the last 30 years as OP asks. I hate to make people feel old, but the last 30 years start with 1992. :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni- It was found to be true within the last 30 years, which is how I interpreted the question. Hence the 2011 Nobel. The work was certainly done earlier.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni in fairness, there’s nothing about this story that suggests it couldn’t have transpired in exactly the same way if this discovery had been made 10 or 20 years ago (or even today for that matter). It seems to me that in the physical sciences, more than in pure mathematics, there is still a fair bit of room even today for “maverick” discoveries to be made that would be doubted or even denounced as impossible by the scientific establishment of the day.

Comment: @DanRomik- That's an interesting point. There is always a finite possibility of discovering some new phenomenon, material or resource that changes an existing reality in the physical sciences.

Comment: I think the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture might fit under the relaxed proven within the last 30 years rule

Comment: Of course Pauling had some "interesting" ideas of his own in later life

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, Linus Pauling was the **real crank**, promoting Vitamin C as a cure for all illnesses including cancer. Fortunately, Vitamin C is cheap, so he is hardly as bad as those quacks who promote their own hundred-thousand-dollar cancer treatment.

Comment: @user21820 on top of that, it's cheap and not massively harmful even in the doses he advocated

Comment: Yes, that's a great example; though the guy was not an outsider at all.

Comment: Your link shows Shechtman was not an amateur.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - Indeed, which is why I mentioned that right on top.

Comment: @Dilworth When he kept insisting that quasicrystals do exist he was called  a crank and was basically fired from the lab where he was working.

Comment: @NickS That's simply not true. Shechtman continued to work with NBS/NIST for decades after the discovery. Four out of five of the seminal quasicrystal papers listed on his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Shechtman) have NBS/NIST co-authors.

Comment: @jeguyer Working for at the same institute and working for the same person are NOT the same thing. My comment is based on a talk by Shechtman I attended. Anyhow, check this interview with him: https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/jan/06/dan-shechtman-nobel-prize-chemistry-interview

Comment: "The bad reaction was the head of my laboratory, who came to my office one day and, smiling sheepishly, put a book on x-ray diffraction on my desk and said, 'Danny, please read this book and you will understand that what you are saying cannot be.' And I told him, you know, I don't need to read this book, I teach at the Technion, and I know this book, and I'm telling you my material is not in the book."He came back a couple of days later and said to me, 'Danny, you are a disgrace to my group. I cannot be with you in the same group.' So I left the group and found another group....

Comment: I'm aware of what story he's decided to tell. I'm also aware of how many people he's hurt in the process. He was not fired, "basically" or otherwise.

Answer (score 58):

**Note:** As Federico Poloni pointed out, the OP requested an example from the last 30, and my example below is from ~70 years ago. This was careless on my part so I apologize. Nonetheless, I think my post is informative so I will keep it up. I guess it goes to show you how rare these examples really are.

Yes, a very concrete and relevant example exists. In 1952, [Kurt Heegner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Heegner) published a proof resolving a very significant part of the [class number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem). Some sources say he was an engineer while others say he was a high school teacher, but all accounts say he was someone interested in higher level math without being a mathematician by profession. Unfortunately, his proof was dismissed because it contained a few errors, and it was more or less agreed that his paper was not valuable. He died in 1965 before his proof was recognized as salvageable by Harold Stark in the late 1960s. The result is now called the [Stark–Heegner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem).

Comment: This is a good example, but it's worth noting that Heegner's paper was published in Mathematische Zeitschrift, and so apparently made it past some level of peer review. So he arguably wasn't regarded as a crank so much as an amateur who made a good effort but didn't quite pull it off. *Still*, very much in the ballpark of what was being asked for. Interesting story!

Comment: This is a non-example. Heegner did not have a professor position, apparently he never sought one, but he was by no means an outsider or a crank. According to German Wikipedia, he had several math papers published in Crelle and Math. Zeit. prior to his famous one. He had a habilitation (!) in mathematics, and was in contact with a few established mathematicians, including E. Schmidt, Weber and Hasse.

Comment: Submitting this as a comment since it's another "timed out" case, I think that the Alvarez hypothesis regarding dinosaur extinction should be considered since Luis Alvarez was an outsider in the field of paleontology and his contribution was derided as a "crank theory" for a decade or more. I think that there are probably other examples of Manhattan Project physicists switching to other fields and- initially at least- being considered maverick outsiders.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what exactly Heegner's academic status was. His English [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Heegner) calls him a "private scholar", which I suspect might be a mistranslation of [*Privatdozent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatdozent). If so, that would place him at the very upper border of the difference between "amateur" and "professional".

Comment: I’d heard this story many times and had no idea Heegner had a habilitation!  This does not seem to be widely known among mathematicians.  The German Wikipedia page has a lot more info than the English one and it would be a great service for someone bilingual to update the English page to include more of the info on the German page.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: However, the German Wikipedia page does not call him Privatdozent but Privatgelehrter and says that apparently a) he never tried to get a permanent position at at a university and b) he seems to have done the habilitation for the purpose of being recognized in the field of mathematics [for this question: did quite something to not be considered a crank]. (Privatdozent would IMHO be very clearly inside the professional league)

Answer (score 38):

Research into mRNA-based therapy, including mRNA-based vaccines, was for a long time not considered positively by much of the scientific establishment.  The word *crank* goes too far, but it appears the scientific consensus at the time was that this research was not promising.  This continued well into the last 30 years.

For example, [Katalin Karikó](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katalin_Karik%C3%B3) was demoted by the University of Pennsylvania in 1995 after several grant applications for mRNA-based therapy were rejected as her peers in the scientific community thought these to be not promising.  She [persisted](https://www.wbur.org/commonhealth/2021/02/12/brutal-science-system-mrna-pioneer), but her *key finding of a chemical modification of mRNA to render it non-immunogenic was rejected by the journals Nature and Science, but eventually accepted by the niche publication "Immunity"* in 2005 (quote from Wikipedia).  Today, she works for BioNTech and, since 2020, has received numerous awards for her ground-breaking work preparing for mRNA-based therapy, including COVID-19 vaccines.

Further reading: Christina Frangou, *Researchers looking for mRNA were ridiculed by colleagues. Luckily, that didn’t stop them.*.  In: MacLeans.  [Available online](https://www.macleans.ca/society/science/scientists-mrna-covid-vaccines/).

Comment: Wow! She should be on the cover pages given how many lives have her mRNA-based vaccines saved in this year alone.

Comment: @Gerrit - Kariko is featured in an article in *Time* magazine's Person of the Year issue (27 December 2021), along with Drew Weissman, Kizzemekia Corbett, and Barney Graham, all for their work on mRNA vaccine development.

Comment: @FailedScientist Along with other key contributors, she should be.

Comment: I dislike this example. It's not ridicule to point out reasons why an idea won't work, even if those reasons are then overcome in the future. The implication is that this advance was obvious, when in fact it was the result of careful work overcoming major technical hurdles. It does the scientists who did that work a disservice by minimizing how hard it was to do (and also fails to note that as soon as they had data to suggest the idea would work, they were *buried* in an avalanche of VC money).

Comment: OP asked for outsiders/amateurs, and she definitely was not one.

Comment: @CJR I have edited the word "ridicule" out of my answer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni She was not outside of academia, but failing grant applications and rejected papers suggest that her work was not taken as seriously as it perhaps should have been.  Hindsight is 20/20, of course, but that applies to any scientific contribution that is only recognised (much) later.

Comment: If grant and paper rejections means you're an outsider then we're all outsiders.

Comment: Yes, the nominal establishment of science has changed. Back then they believed, that good results advertise themselves.

Comment: @CJR That + demotion.  The remarkable point is not grand and paper rejections as such, but grand and paper rejections for work that is later having a huge impact and winning many awards.

Comment: @SamGinrich unfortunately in too many instances *bad results* still positively advertise themselves…

Answer (score 16):

I'm adding another answer since it's fundamentally different from the other one I've written, being arguably not by an outsider, but it was groundbreaking and happened within the last 30 years.

[Li Wenliang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Wenliang) was one of the first to identify that 2019-nCoV was a new virus, but his hospital and immediate supervisors warned him about "publishing untrue statements". As I write this, we are still dealing with the fallout of that discovery.

Comment: Wasn't me more of a whistleblower silenced for political reasons than someone accused of being a crank, though?

Comment: @gerrit his colleagues apparently decided he was wrong and pushing an untrue position, however, which is similar to being a crank. It's still not an ideal example though, I agree.

Comment: @Allure There is enough mix of politics to say that it is not clear whether the dismissal was due to scientific, academic, or political reasons.

Answer (score 15):

I can think of some examples of people who were thought of as cranks and then had a great result, but they're mostly not "outsiders" and mostly not within 30 years.  For example, my understanding (from stories told at a conference I attended) is that Apéry was widely thought of as a crank at the time he proved his [remarkable theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_theorem).  But he had a math Ph.D. and was a professor at a university.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal Because it does not fit the requirements of the question, like many other answers here.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately right now I can't think of an example from the past 30 years. These go back 150 years.

- Gregor Mendel was a priest when he wrote the defining papers of genetic inheritance. At the time his papers were [largely ignored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Mendel#Initial_reception_of_Mendel%27s_work), but today Mendelian inheritance is widely taught in high school biology classes.
- Alfred Wegener espoused the theory of [continental drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Wegener#Continental_drift_theory) and was met with ridicule, although it is widely accepted today. In his lifetime he was best-known as a meteorologist and polar explorer, not geologist; hence he was an outsider to the field.
- [Nicholas Christofilos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Christofilos) developed strong focusing in accelerator physics that went unnoticed for several years until rediscovered independently by professionals.

Comment: Mendel and Christofilos seem different: the wider scientific establishment didn’t regard their work as wrong, they simply _didn’t_ regard them. Wegener was certainly the example I thought of on seeing the question title, though.

Comment: Mendel's story always hurts me.

Comment: Wegener is an interesting example, because it really did get a lot of ridicule. The others not so much, the normal state of research is for it to be mostly ignored.

Comment: If you insist on going back more than a century, the best choice for someone who was widely considered a crank is probably Semmelweis.  Mind you, I wouldn't really call him an outsider.  @FailedScientist: If Mendel's story hurts you, I can't imagine what you'd think of Semmelweis.

Comment: "Semmelweis's views were much more favorably received in the United Kingdom than on the continent, but he was more often _cited than understood_." Reminds me of Orwell's iconic line from 1984. How dearly I wish I could go back in time and support him..

Answer (score 12):

It's not in maths, and it's just on the cusp of whether you'd consider it in the last 30 years, but...

#### [Demonstrating that gastric ulcers are caused by bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_peptic_ulcer_disease_and_Helicobacter_pylori)

The key research for this was done in the 1980s, and all these researchers were written off as cranks.  It isn't too strong to say that the medical profession were close to unanimous in this, despite the evidence.

Whether this counts depends on where you draw your 30-year line.  Whilst major evidence was presented in the 1980s, in 1992 (30 years ago) the medical profession was still very largely opposed to this and to a large degree still considered them to be cranks.  It took until the mid-late 1990s before it became more widely accepted, and the two key researchers were awarded the Nobel in 2005.

Comment: This is a [very interesting case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Marshall) (in fact, one of the Nobel prize winners gave themselves an ulcer and then cured it). But OP defines "crank" as an amateur with no affiliation to a research institute -- in this case, both Marshall and Warren were were medical doctors, they applied for and received funding for this experiment, and they used their hospital's resources to help with the lab tests.

Comment: The case is very interesting; yet the author were not actually cranks -- they were thought as cranks. In other words, the authors are not real cranks, the real cranks in 1980s were other researchers in the same topic.

Comment: John Lykoudis treated patients with antibiotics. He was fined by Greek authorities,and he could not publish his findings [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lykoudis). And as far as I remember he was not affiliated with a research institution, being a local MD. The "[Helicobacter pioneers](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Helicobacter+Pioneers%3A+Firsthand+Accounts+from+the+Scientists+who+Discovered+Helicobacters+1892+1982-p-9780867930351)" book has a chapter on him "John Lykoudis: The general practitioner in Greece who in 1958 discovered the etiology and a treatment of peptic ulcer disease."

Comment: @HighGPA: there's a risk of self-fulfilling prophecy here: can someone *who's shown to be correct in their solution of a sufficiently important problem* later on actually be a *real* crank?

Comment: @HighGPA The OP worded the question fairly carefully to avoid that point: "*...whose work was considered a crank* ***when published*** *...*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Graham I agree with you. Your example is clearly correct.

Answer (score 10):

An anonymous 4chan poster proved [a lower bound on superpermutations in 2011](https://www.quantamagazine.org/sci-fi-writer-greg-egan-and-anonymous-math-whiz-advance-permutation-problem-20181105/), and an upper bound was then proved by SF writer Greg Egan in 2018. These have since been folded into a 2020 paper by [Engen and Vatter](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00029890.2021.1835384), and validated by other mathematicians in the academy.

A small but important difference from your question is the requirement that they publish "into cyber-space a new manuscript alleged to solve a major open problem in mathematics". The "manuscript" here was a 4chan post on an anime board, and it didn't claim to solve the superpermutation problem in general, just the specific problem of how to watch all of the episodes of a particular show in every possible order.

Greg Egan, though mainly a science fiction writer, is the sort of hard SF writer who is very technical, who has many scientists as fans, and has even collaborated on a few scholarly publications [in quantum computing](http://www.gregegan.net/BIBLIOGRAPHY/Bibliography.html#NonFiction). He posted it not as a LaTeX manuscript but as a [HTML page](http://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/Superpermutations/Superpermutations.html), on his personal website, in full late nineties [web brutalist](https://brutalist-web.design/) style.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the "late nineties" qualifier on web brutalist style, when the Egan page is from 2018, and the style guide is from 2021?

Comment: Well, it's kind of a rhetorical aside, but I would argue web brutalist style was almost the only way to publish on the web in the late nineties. The brutalist manifesto is an attempt to describe and valorize that as an explicit style choice. Egan's personal website has been online since 2008 at that address, and previously at an [ISP-specific address since 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/2021*/http://www.netspace.net.au/~gregegan/index.html). He's stuck with relatively unadorned web pages throughout due to inertia or utility, and thus with the web brutalist style.

Answer (score 4):

Galois is still  the only example of an amateurish mathematician without even a high school diploma who solved a famous problem. He was getting no credit for this because famous mathematicians (Cauchy and others) considered him crank.

Comment: Great example, but I don't think he's the only such example, at a minimum there's also Ramanujan.

Comment: Ramanujan had many great results but did not a solve a famous unsolved problem.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I doubt Ramanujan was considered a crank. Just obscure in Britain.

Comment: OP asks "in the last 30 years" though.

Comment: Ramanujan did not have formal University education. But of course he had he had more formal education than Galois.

Comment: My answer implies that in the last 30 (or even 100) years there were  no examples. Moreover there were no examples in the last 500 years except Galois.

Comment: Ramanujan was not a crank. To the contrary, he was easily recognized by serious mathematicians as a mathematical talent of the first order. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073318/why-how-was-hardy-impressed-with-ramanujan-s-work-prior-to-seeing-any-proofs-of) for example.

Comment: @DanRomik: Ramanujan had to write to multiple professors before Hardy recognized him as a genius.  One professor wrote back and basically called him a crank because of his result that 1+2+3+... = -1/12

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft that result has been known since Euler, so all this illustrates is that that professor was an incompetent mathematician himself, and unqualified to judge other people’s mathematical abilities. Again, Ramanujan was not a crank by any conventionally accepted definition of that term.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. It is not true at all that Galois was considered to be a crank at the time. Cauchy rejected his first submissions, but it is a myth that he did not appreciate Galois' work. In fact, it is probably more accurate to say that Cauchy was one of the people who encouraged Galois. See for example: "Rothman, T. (1982). Genius and Biographers: The Fictionalization of Evariste Galois. The American Mathematical Monthly, 89(2), 84-106"

Comment: @spin: What you wrote is wrong. Cauchy knew that Galois had no formal education, no affiliation with anything and the text submitted by Galois was incomprehensible while claiming to solve a famous open problem which Cauchy himself was working for long time. What else could Cauchy think? The rejection letter was standard: you should submit your paper elsewhere. Poisson was more direct in his rejection letter of the same paper: he just declared the paper incomprehensible.  Rothman's text in the Monthly is a known opinion, but not the mainstream one.

Comment: @markvs: In their report Poisson and Lacroix criticized the paper of Galois for two things: 1) it is unclear 2) assuming it is correct, the condition that Galois gives for solvability by radicals is impractical. There is commentary and a translation of the report in Peter Neumann's book on Galois. Poisson and Lacroix rejected the paper by Galois - and rightly so since the paper was badly written. But reading their report I don't think they considered him to be a crank or a circle-squarer.

Comment: @spin: You are entitled to your opinions.

Comment: @markvs: So are you, but mainstream references would disagree with your answer. I recommend the book by Peter Neumann and references therein as a starting point for learning more.

Comment: @spin: I have read the book, and I know Peter Neumann.

Comment: @markvs From $\Pi$MN's book, Lacroix-Poisson's report: "Be that as it may, we have made every effort to understand Mr Galois’ proof. His reasoning is neither clear enough nor well enough developed for us to have been able to judge its correctness, and we are in no position to give an idea of it in this report [...] One may therefore wait until the author will have published his work in its
entirely before forming a final opinion; but given the present state of the part
that he has submitted to theAcademy, we cannot propose to you that you give
it your approval." Sounds like spin is right.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: It seems that you have not seen referee reports on crank papers.  Poisson report is of that kind, their opinion about the paper is absolutely clear. It was not written for you, and  Galois understood it, precisely.

Comment: @markvs Well, I disagree. I have been an editor and received crank papers. They are instant desk rejections. Lacroix and Poisson would not have wasted their time with a crank. They have clearly read the paper, and have considered the mathematics. But maybe we have different definitions of a crank, of course.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: "They have clearly read the paper" is not true It is clear that  they did not read it. They might **try** to read it but obviously were unable to read the text.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a "crank," as he was a PhD-holding lecturer at a small university (just didn't have the most prestigious publication record or anything), but [Yitang Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang) may be the closest modern example of what you're looking for.

His work is related to the (still open) twin prime conjecture which states that there are infinitely many pairs of primes with difference 2 (like 3 and 5 or 11 and 13). His theorem showed that there are infinitely many pairs of primes with difference at most c where c is an explicit constant given in his paper. This result was published in the Annals of Maths, often considered to be the most prestigious math journal.

Comment: Right, there's outsiders who weren't cranks and cranks who weren't outsiders, but not people who were both cranks and outsiders.

Comment: @NoahSnyder and there are people who are neither cranks nor (properly speaking) outsiders, such as Yitang Zhang.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of him. But he was a reputable established mathematical, just not in a top-top US school. He was never considered a crank.

Comment: @Dilworth : I don't think Yitang Zhang was "a reputable established mathematician", he had very few publications, and his work on the Jacobian conjecture was wrong, as far as I know.

Comment: @akhmeteli, well, he was reputable at least and has an affiliation. He wasn't considered top indeed.

Comment: He was not in a research position.  He was a professional college math teacher, not an established researcher

Comment: @NoahSnyder, correct. I didn't know that, and indeed I see now that he was only a lecturer at NH. That said, his work was never considered a crank-work, only surprised people because he was unknown and had no research-affliation.

Comment: @akhmeteli Could you please offer some references on Yitang's paper on Jacobian conjecture that is wrong or cranky?

Comment: @HighGPA : Now that you asked... I begin to have doubts. My memory was that he wrote a wrong preprint in arxiv on the Jacobian conjecture, but I failed to find his preprint on this topic. Looks like his PhD thesis was about the J. conjecture, but I failed to find his publications on this topic. I found something about his arxiv article on a different topic being wrong: (cntd)

Comment: @HighGPA : In 2007, Zhang had published a preprint paper claiming that he had proved that...(https://science.thewire.in/the-sciences/yitang-zhang-landau-siegel-zeroes-riemann-hypothesis/#:~:text=In%202007%2C%20Zhang%20had%20published,ideas%20developed%20in%20that%20paper.) I cannot vouch for the source though.

Answer (score -3):

Everyone ...

You might be shocked by this answer. It goes against the grain of the conventional wisdom. This answer is clearly the opposite of the accepted answer and OP's personal preference. But, do hear me out.

The OP defines an "amateur" as:

> "someone with no formal affiliation to a reputable research institute,
> **or** someone who does not have any track record of peer-reviewed publications in reputable journals or conferences in the area"

The rest of my answer focuses on amateurs who fall under the second category. The word "**or**" means that fulfilling only one of the two conditions is enough to identify an amateur and gives a precise answer.

To give a precise answer and avoid controversy, I will further narrow down to the subset of true amateurs who has not only no reputable journal ppaers, but also has published some mistaken works. "Publish" here means making things public. It includes papers, preprints, presentation slides, conference papers, and webposts.

I admit that I have been a true amateur. I have published some flawed works. I've made a lot of mistakes. I've made mistakes in an undergraduate paper that was later published in a college journal accessible to the public. I've made mistakes in the talks in my school (and those talks are open to the public). I've made mistakes in preprints. I've made countless mistakes in webposts. I am not a genius and it takes me a long time to understand a simple concept. I was and I am still a strict amateur. Yet, after nine years, I finally published in a reputable journal.

Am I alone? Of course not, almost all of my friends were similar. We were all once cranky, freshy, and amateury. We were all once naive, inexperienced, and unskilled. We were all once unprofessional, clumsy, and sloppy. We all made some blunders. Some blunders were silly, some were serious. Maybe Sally made fewer blunders because she was talented. Maybe Joe made more blunders because he took too many naps. But **eventually**, most of us managed to publish at least one paper. While I won't say one reputable publication is something ground-breaking, it is certainly an achievement and break-through in our narrow fields.

Before that paper, we had zero reputable publication. Our preprints got rejected everywhere, sometimes even without a line of comment.

Yes, we were cranks. Yes, we made mistakes. Yes, doing research is extremely difficult. Yes, it is even harder to get established researchers to recognize our works. Yes, there are many dark sides and unpleasant realities every day everywhere. But, a true hero will never forget their dream. A true hero will never give up. A true hero will stand against many challenges. A true hero will see the light through the dark clouds. A true hero will fight for the truth. A true hero will inspire others with their passion. A true hero will rise above their doubts and fears.

So let's finish my first sentence in the beginning of this answer.

... Everyone, in my small circle, was once an amateur, once a crank, once a misfit, stupid yet young, mediocre yet confident. But, you only fail  when you lose hope.

Everyone has been there.

---

Update: yesterday the OP updated their meaning of "affiliation to reputable research institute" to "tenure-track faculty, permanent scientists, and similar roles". This means that, according to the OP's definition, all students, visitors, research assistants and all other affiliates without a publication in reputable journal are amateurs.

So my answer strongly hold. Any students who made mistakes and later published a reputable journal fulfills all criteria. My answer applies to all students in fields that advisors are usually not heavily involved in student's research (for example, my small field), and applies to undergraduate students who does not have a very dedicated advisor. This answer does not apply to some scientific fields that advisors must be heavily involved and coauthor with students, and does not apply to extremely talented students who got their first paper quickly accepted in the first venue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/118348)

Comment: @Buzz What I am describing are amateurs with no publication record. They have papers that were rejected everywhere, even without a serious comment. Of course, the editor consider the work as crankery or non-serious. But finally they convince the editor and referee that their work is correct. This applies to all researchers when they were young, before they had a PhD, before they were recognized as an "insider".

Comment: I imagine it's quite rare for most researchers to receive a "crankery or non-serious" decision for their papers, even their first ones. Anecdotally, the first paper I wrote was accepted at the first venue I submitted it to, as well.

Comment: Not every amateur will be called a crank. This is because we are  in a 21 century civilized world, where professionalism, respect and politeness is appreciated. No one called me a crank. But I know I am one. Calling someone "crank" in referee report is non-professional: nobody will use the word.

Comment: @Allure How about your first "publication" according to the definition above? Is your first webpost, first presentation, or first preprint free of mistakes?

Comment: @HighGPA Are you thinking of school assignments? In that case, I wouldn't say those were free of mistakes, but I generally passed.

Comment: @Allure I'd say you are extremely talented to have your first paper quickly published. Congrats! I know some associate professors in top 30 US school. They told me that in average each of their papers needs to be submitted for seven times before finally published.

Comment: Reply to comments that I did not answer OP's question: Note that, speaking in formal logics, by "raising the bar", I am putting more constraints on my answer, and I am answering a generalized version of OP's question, which include OP's question as a special case. So my answer directly applies to OP's question.

Answer (score -11):

I'll go one better, and suggest an entire field that was regarded as crankery, but now is viewed as a legitimate field of inquiry: ufology. Prior to the American government releasing declassified video evidence of UFO encounters and then issuing official statements that they're real and of unknown origin, it was widely regarded as the work of cranks.

Now, the [head of Astronomy at Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avi_Loeb) is launching the [Galileo Project](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/galileo) to try to record hard evidence of them, without requiring the use of military equipment.

Comment: I really wish that people who downvoted answers were courteous enough to at least leave a comment explaining why, and how the answer could be improved. I've added some links to relevant sources, if that helps any.

Comment: @apkg Well, the US government apparently has, according to their public statements to Congress, but almost all of the recordings are classified because they're reveal technical details about the capabilities of US military radar systems and the like. That's a fair point to make, though.

Comment: A field studying unidentified objects in the sky should not be conflated with the religion of assuming such objects are alien-operated spacecraft.

Comment: Actually, this is a good example I've learned only lately, from Harvard.

Comment: I am one of the downvoters. The reason for my downvote is that, regardless of whether you think that ufology is now “a legitimate field of inquiry” (whatever that means), this actually has nothing to do with the actual question. OP asked about work that was considered crankery but was then _validated and proved correct_. Ufology has not been “validated and proved correct” in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @DanRomik, it wasn't proved correct, but it now became a legitimate area of study it seems. So the problem with this answer is that it is not mathematical, like all other non-mathematical answers here. Basically, I believe the only "formally correct" answers is yours.

Comment: @Dilworth I upvoted several of the other answers that are non-mathematical and/or not “formally correct” in the sense you’re describing. The problem with this answer has nothing to do with those qualities.

Comment: I think this is a good example. Although no evidence of UFO is validated, there are some theorems related to alien civilization that is proven to be correct mathematically.

Answer (score -15):

[This Riemann Hypothesis guy](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3321924/It-pays-good-maths-Nigerian-professor-solves-156-year-old-Riemann-problem-scoop-1million-prize.html) was **not** an amateur or a crank but he was not working at a major institution and bigwigs of his own *métier* had never heard of him.

Over a century ago Gosset, as an experimental brewer at Guinness' (and using the pseudonym, Student, lest he be accused of publishing industrial secrets by his employer), published his valuable work on the t-distribution.

I'd say there are quite a few "outsiders" (i.e not established names from universities, research institutes or national labs) but I doubt if many who have no professional qualification, e.g. at least a primary degree, would bother to publish in academic journals.

Those disclosing their innovations indirectly, like people applying for patents, are often without any formal qualification in the relevant field. James Dyson is an example of this sort of thing.
His ~ 5,000 experiments on cyclone parameters showed that there *was* a way to use cyclones to separate particles less than 20 microns from air. This was a direct contradiction of numerous "experts" - several of them apparently professors of computational fluid dynamics - who denied it was feasible.

But what are you getting at with all this ? That someone seeking recognition for solving a major problem ought to prepare the ground for that by solving a series of less challenging - and therefore more easily verified and published - problems first ?  That there is a sort of hierarchy or snobbery within the scientific community ? This is evident from the very manner of so many scientists inside and outside academia. And it's not confined to science either. You see it in how attention towards an individual is accumulated in the domain of sport, investing, community activism, the arts, even in religious affairs. Of course, it **is** stupid to overlook a potentially valuable contribution just because it comes from a newbee or someone whose previous contributions have been unimpressive. But it's all in the game of life and we have to handle it.

But yes, it certainly is healthy when someone unknown in a field defies the "breeders' guide" predictions of his/her talent. It gets everyone back to the basic task of scientific inquiry rather than following macrotrends like some old pol.

Comment: Your “Riemann hypothesis guy” didn’t actually solve the Riemann hypothesis, so that’s completely irrelevant to what OP is asking about. And your other examples also don’t answer the actual question.

Comment: I'm going on the OP's definition of a crank, i.e.  *someone with no formal affiliation to a reputable research institute, or someone who does not have any track record of peer-reviewed publications in reputable journals or conferences in the area.* I think this definition covers both Gosset (since he published under a pseudonym) and Dyson.

Comment: That’s OP’s definition of an _amateur_, not of a crank. Two completely different things.

Comment: Note that your linked articles contradicts its own headline in the text. The headline clearly says he already won the million dollars from the Clay institute whereas the text says the Clay institue was not willing to comment on his proof. The article is already 7 years old and afaik the prize is still not awarded. The Daily Mail is not the most reliable source :-)

Comment: *example in the last 30 years in which such an amateur whose work was considered a crank when published*   Where amateur and crank have the definitions provided by the OP. Clearly (and OP's question didn't read so clear, at least to me) a pure crank is not what the OP is looking for. He wants a poorly regarded professional whose work, esp. w.r.t. to major questions, would be read as crankery by the big-names of that field.

Comment: @quarague  I think you'll agree that the general tone of the article was positive towards Dr Enoch. As you point out, they didn't say his solution was accepted. But they didn't say it was rejected either. Not being privy to their long deliberations I was ignorant of the Clay Institute decision.

Comment: Gosset was certainly not a crank (and wasn't seen as one at the time). He collaborated with more mathematically-trained statisticians who encouraged his work. This is pretty common in statistics. Many novel contributions have come from applied scientists who needed to analyze the kind of data for which "real statisticians" hadn't developed good methods yet; but once the problem became clear, statisticians worked with the scientists to make the new methods more rigorous and thoroughly understood. Some contributors may have been amateurs, but not seen as cranks.